# Variables not receiving amounts? Python

Tags: python, module, return

When I run my program, none of the variables that I am declaring are getting their values. I did remember to use the `return` statement, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
def main():
    time_Amount = getTime()

    seconds = getSeconds(time_Amount)
    minutes = getMinutes(seconds)
    hours = getHours(minutes)
    days = getDays(hours)

    printBreakDown(days, hours, minutes, seconds)

def getTime():
    time_Amount = int(input("Enter time in seconds: "))
    while (time_Amount == 0):
        seconds = int(input("Enter a non-zero amount of seconds: "))
    return time_Amount

def getSeconds(time_Amount):
    seconds = time_Amount % 60
    return seconds
def getMinutes(seconds):
    minutes = seconds % 60
    return minutes
def getHours(minutes):
    hours = minutes % 24
    return hours
def getDays(hours):
    days = hours % 365
    return days

def printBreakDown(days, hours, minutes, seconds):
    print("--------Break Down--------")
    print(days, "day(s), ", hours, "hour(s), ",
          minutes, "minute(s), ", seconds, "second(s)")

main()
```

Comment: `minutes = seconds % 60`. That doesn't sound right to me. So if `seconds` equals 59, then `minutes` also equals 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the modulus (`%`) operator the way you are attempting to. If your value passed is smaller than your divisor, your value will remain the same. 
This is hardly an appropriate way to convert minutes to hours (*and so on*), and results in your strange values.

What you most likely want to use is store your precise value with each division, and use the [floor division operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) `//` to determine how many days/hours/minutes/seconds.

To illustrate the difference between `%` and `//`:

```
>>> 10 // 24
0
>>> 10 % 24
10
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `datetime` module to calculate this much more succinctly:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
def main():
    time_Amount = timedelta( seconds = int(input('Enter time in seconds: ')))

    while (time_Amount == timedelta(seconds = 0)):
        time_Amount = timedelta( seconds = int(input("Enter a non-zero amount of seconds: ")))    

    calc_time = datetime(1,1,1) + time_Amount
    print("--------Break Down--------")
    print("%d day(s), %d hour(s), %d minute(s), %d second(s)" %
          (calc_time.day-1, calc_time.hour, calc_time.minute, calc_time.second))
```

***How this works***:

- First we create a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object of seconds from the user input. Essentially this is an object reflecting a *duration*, and can be expressed in many different units of time.
- `datetime(1,1,1) + time_Amount` takes a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object of 1 year, 1 month, and 1 day, and adds our `timedelta` duration in seconds.
- We use string formatting to idiomatically take out the respective day, hour, minute, and second from our `datetime` object.

Were you to want to have a month or year variable, you would have to format for them and subtract 1 from them accordingly, accessing with `calc_time.month` and `calc_time.year` respectively.

**Outputs:**

```
>>>main()
Enter time in seconds: 10000
--------Break Down--------
0 day(s), 2 hour(s), 46 minute(s), 40 second(s)
```

Comment: I will try this. Can you explain to me what the `calc_time = datetime(1,1,1) + time_Amount` does? And also what does `time_Amount = timedelta( seconds = int(input('Enter time in seconds: '))) Thank you!

Comment: @Ghost_Programmer Also let me know if there's anything that is still unclear with my `datetime` alternative.

Comment: *Quote* "We use string formatting to idiomatically take out the respective day, hour, minute, and second from our `datetime` object" *End Quote* ... and that is why you put `calc_time.day-1`? That makes sense. If I was to put in a `month` variable,how would I go about that? To avoid comment-flooding, how would the `Floor Division Operator` `//` work compared to the ``Modulus Operator` `%`? Thank you for updating your answer by the way!

Comment: @Ghost_Programmer Updated my answer again, and no worries, glad I could help.

Comment: Alright. All makes sense. Thank you very much for your help! I have only been using Python for about 5 months and I am still learning all the time. Just yesterday I learned how to accurately delete specific strings from a text file and how to access the directory. Next lesson is `tuples`, but that's not the point. Thank you for all of your help and have an excellent day! Programming Novice, -Ghost_Programmer

Answer (score 2):

First thing I see is that you write `seconds` instead of `time_Amount` in the following function.

```
def getTime():
    time_Amount = int(input("Enter time in seconds: "))
    while (time_Amount == 0):
        # Check this line
        time_Amount = int(input("Enter a non-zero amount of seconds: "))
    return time_Amount
```

What you had was:

```
def getTime():
    time_Amount = int(input("Enter time in seconds: "))
    while (time_Amount == 0):
        seconds = int(input("Enter a non-zero amount of seconds: "))
    return time_Amount
```

If the user enters 0 on the first line, then the `while` loop will be entered prompting the user to enter a non-zero value. The user then enters 10, and `seconds` is assigned the value of 10. Note that `time_Amount` is still 0 because you never modified it. The `loop` condition is checked, and it stays inside of the `while` loop.

Comment: I don't think I understand what it is you are trying to explain. Where should I have put `seconds` in `getTime()`?

Comment: `seconds` doesn't belong in `getTime()`. The way you had it meant that if you entered the while loop, you would go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Hmm. Alright. I thought that was `Input Validation`. We were taught about that in my course. I was in the mindset that if the user entered the loop, if the user picked a number that was not 0, they would escape the loop and either way, it would return the variable `time_Amount` with the input.

Comment: That is input validation, but you're never modifying the value of `time_Amount` so it can't leave the loop.

Comment: Can you explain then how I would modify the value of `time_Amount` so that when they user escapes the loop, the value would have changed?

Comment: My answer does that. You just assign the value to `time_Amount`

Comment: My apologies. I must've been a little bit off when I wrote the original code. That's why I was at a mis-understanding. Thank you for your help, Dehli! Have a great day! Programming Novice, -Ghost_Programmer

Comment: You're very welcome! Good luck in your programming endeavors :)

Comment: And you as well, my friend! :)